# jQuery UI append to

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal-dialog, appendto

Having an issues is appending a dialog modal with table information from an iframe that triggers once it gets to a point in a series of drop downs from a pie chart. When I get to the point from the view itself the dialog works just fine, move around and exits just fine and is centered. When I append to the parent view the dialog gives the cursor as movable, but isn't movable.

This is the the javascript I'm using to pull the append the iframe to the parent page. But I can't seem  to get any positioning to work and can't seem to get it to work as a true dialog modal.

This is the div I'm using to pull the iframe into the parent page.

```
 <div id="chartsright">
      <iframe id="inventory_charts" frameborder="0" align='center' src="<?php echo
       site_url('sales_diagnostics/inventory_charts');?>" class="charts" 
       scrolling="no"></iframe> 
 </div>
```

this is the PHP/Javascript I'm using in the frame page itselft to append to the parent page

```
    <?php
    if(isset($popup_div))
    {
      echo "$(function() {
    $( \"#dialog\" ).dialog( 
    { 
       minWidth: 1000,
       appendTo: parent.document.getElementById('chartsright'),
       position: { 
           \"in\": $('.inventory')
                     }
       });

       });";
    }
    ?>
```